# Function to return a function var

Tags: javascript

Can I have something like this where function returns a var which in itself is a function that performs operation on a DOM element?

```
var foo = function() {

    var blah = function() {
        document.getElementById('box').style.color="red";
    };

    return blah;

};

setTimeout(function() {

    foo();

}, 2000);



<div id="box">This is some div</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the tips, it does work as you pointed out.
a little followup...
Can I do similar with an object returned?

```
var foo = function() {

    var blah = function() {
        document.getElementById('box').style.color="red";
    };

    var flop = function() {
        document.getElementById('box').style.color="green";
    };

    return {
        blah: blah,
        flop: flop
    };

};


var newInstance = foo();

setTimeout(function() {

    newInstance.blah;

}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {

    newInstance.flop;

}, 4000);



<div id="box">This is some div</div>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding where the return value should be received. Do you mean something like `setTimeout(foo(), 2000)`? A little more context would help.

Comment: @cookiemonster I'm pretty sure that's what's intended, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Pointy: Yep, it all depends on when everything inside `foo` yet outside `blah` should be executed. There's nothing like vague examples using meaningless function names to becloud the actual problem.

Comment: Stop wrapping your function references in anonymous functions like that!  That's the root of your problem. `newInstance.blah` is a reference to a function, so it can be passed **directly** into `setTimeout`.

Comment: got it. thanks. timeOut was for illustrative purposes only but I get your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need to call it like this:

```
foo()();
```

The first set of parenthesis gets the function expression, the second executes the function expression.

Because foo returns a function, I think the code could be written like this:

```
setTimeout(foo(), 2000);
```

Comment: what are you talking about ?

Comment: In his code, the person asking has an expression that gets a function but doesn't call it. He needs to call the function to get the function returned, then call that function which was returned.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that.  Your example is close.  What you want to do is:

```
setTimeout(function() {

    var result = foo();
    result();

}, 2000);
```

or more concisely:

```
setTimeout(function() {

    foo()();

}, 2000);
```

The inner `foo()` call returns the function, and now you need to call that function by sticking another pair of parens onto that result.

UPDATE

Additionally, since `setTimeout()` expects a function as the first parameter anyways, you can just do this:

```
setTimeout(foo(), 2000);
```

This way you are calling `foo()` which returns the function, and passing that function directly to `setTimeout()`.  Your brain getting dizzy yet?  =)

Answer (score 1):

Take the anonymous function wrapper away:

```
setTimeout(foo(), 2000);
```

That'll pass into `setTimeout` the function that's returned when you call "foo". You don't need to wrap it in another anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in JavaScript are first class citizens, so the answer is yes: `foo()()`.